# Run php (Ajax) when pressing button

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, variables

First i run a query to my database and get all info about a costumer with a spesific customerID:

```
    <?php

include 'connect-database.php';


   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Kunde WHERE kundenr LIKE '".$_GET['kundenr']."' ";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
   if( $stmt == false){
       die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), tue) );
   }
   echo "<table border='1'>";
   echo "<tr><th>Kundenr</th><th>Fornavn</th><th>Etternavn</th><th>Tlf</th><th>Epost</th><th>Produktnr</th><th>Adresse</th></tr>";



while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td><a href="kundedisplay.php?kundenr='.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</a></td>';
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";

}      echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>";


echo '<button id="redigerkunde" type="button">Rediger Kunde</button>';
```

You can see the link in first row "`<a href="kundedisplay.php?kundenr='.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</a>`, that link is to this page.

What i want to do is: 
When i press the button "redigerkunde" (means edit customer), I want to run a new php file, using ajax. I get this to work with

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").on('click', function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "php/ajax.php",

                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("p").text(data);

                }
            });
   });

</script>
```

BUT the problem is, how can i send right customerID to this ajax.php page? $row[0] contains the customerID.

right now in the ajax.php:

```
echo '"'.$_GET['kundenr'].'"';
```

Want it to echo the customerID to the person i select with the button from my kundedisplay.php page

Thanks!

Comment: you want to pass more than 1 `kundenr` value to `ajax.php`

Comment: Yes, i might have i list of 3 customers, and I then want the button to select one of them, and send that 'kundenr' to ajax.php

Comment: How to select only one??

Comment: I did something like this when i pressed a table row: `echo "<td onClick='lodaproduct(" . $row[0] . ")'>" . $row[0] . "</td>";`  Don't now how to do the same with a button..

Comment: first tel me one thing, for each row, you have separate buttons?

Comment: no, but nevermind, found a way to work around the multiple "kundenr", i just make the user press the CustomerID you want to select first, then there is only one possible 'Kundenr'. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you want to use only one button you can use checkboxes to select which row you want to edit.
Try this.

```
<?php
include 'connect-database.php';
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM Kunde WHERE kundenr LIKE '" . $_GET['kundenr'] . "' ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt == false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), tue));
}
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th></th><th>Kundenr</th><th>Fornavn</th><th>Etternavn</th><th>Tlf</th><th>Epost</th><th>Produktnr</th><th>Adresse</th></tr>";
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='toedit' value='" . $row[0] . "'></td>";
    echo '<td><a href="kundedisplay.php?kundenr=' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[0] . '</a></td>';
    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<table>";
echo '<button class="redigerkunde" type="button">Rediger Kunde</button>';
```

And in Java Script you can type:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "php/ajax.php",
                data: {id:$('.toedit:checked:first').val()}
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("p").text(data);

                }
            });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey again! is it possible to display a form in the ajax.php file? when i press "Rediger Kunde" button, i want a form to be displayed, that the user have to fill out? Or is this not possible when using Ajax like this? I only get the form in plain text..

Comment: Yes, you can. In this case returned data will be HTML and you must use returned data like $('div').html(data). Your `form` will be displayed inside of `div` element.

Comment: Okay, but what should I put in <form action="ajax.php" > field? If I make it the same as my main page, it won't save, if I make it ajax.php, it just get me to the ajax.php page (I don't want to be redirected to any page).

Answer (score 3):

To send variables through ajax use, `data`

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "php/ajax.php",
            data: {key:value,key:value},// this line.
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $("p").text(data);

            }
        });
```

You can send n number of key => value pairs.

**Next:**

You are using `post` in ajax, so in ajax.php,

```
echo $_POST['kundenr'];// no need of so may quotes.
```

Comment: Thank You! this work fine when iam only have one Customer.

Comment: Only one question: the value i want to send is: ` $_GET['kundenr']` is there a way to rename it, so i can remove the `$_GET` ? something like: `$_GET['kundenr'] = kundenr; `  and then write in the `<script>` : `data: {key: kundenr}, ` ?

Comment: `$_GET['kundenr'] = "kundenr";` add quotes

Comment: Okay, did it, and in data i wrote: `data: {key: 'kundenr'}, ` it now sendt "kundenr" as a string, not the value I get when echo: `$_GET['kundenr']` When i write : `data: {key: 'kundenr'}, ` it says: The global variable "kundennr" is not declared.

Comment: is should be `$_GET['key']`

Comment: yeah, the `echo $_GET['kundenr'] ` was in the kundedisplay.php page, did it just to check if the variable was correct. in ajax.php i wrot : `$_GET['key'].  I get the error in Kundedisplay.php

Comment: `$_GET['kundenr'] = "kundenr";

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
   
    $("button").on('click', function(){
   
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "php/redigerkunde.php",
                data: {key: 'kundenr'},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("p").text(data);

                }
            });
   });

</script>
`

Comment: while accessing value in `php/redigerkunde.php`, use `$_GET['key']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php

include 'connect-database.php';
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Kunde WHERE kundenr LIKE '".$_GET['kundenr']."' ";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
   if( $stmt == false){
       die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), tue) );
   }
   echo "<table border='1'>";
   echo "<tr><th>Kundenr</th><th>Fornavn</th><th>Etternavn</th><th>Tlf</th><th>Epost</th><th>Produktnr</th><th>Adresse</th></tr>";



while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td><a href="kundedisplay.php?kundenr='.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</a></td>';
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
       echo '<button class="redigerkunde" data-id="'.$row[0].'" type="button">Rediger Kunde</button>';
       echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<table>";
```

And in Java Script you can type:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "php/ajax.php",
                data: {id:$(this).attr("data-id")}
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("p").text(data);

                }
            });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: he has only one button.